# Add text before str_pad in php

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In PrestaShop I use this short code to rename the reference code of an order

```
$order->reference = str_pad($order->id, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order->update();
```

With this code I get reference number like : 000001009
I went to add text "MY" before this number and get format like : MY000001009

Can any one help me?

Comment: Where do you have this code? A module? Directly in a core file?

Comment: By the way, maybe I can't understand your question but a `'MY'.str_pad($order->id, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` don't do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that's to simple

```
$order->reference = "MY" . str_pad($order->id, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order->update();
```

Comment: Hooray XD, if you want put as answered to help other people ;)